# How to reduce the time my code is taking. Changes to the code can be made if necessary. Is there a faster way to run the code

Tags: time, reduce, execution

```
import itertools
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import math
import cmath as cm
#Creating Class
class Three_RPR:
    def __init__(self,end_effector_sideLengths,fixed_coordinates,actuation_distance,delta = 0,lambdas = [0,0,0,0,0,0]):
        self.e = end_effector_sideLengths
        self.F = np.array(fixed_coordinates)
        self.coord1 = self.F[0]
        self.coord2 = self.F[1]
        self.coord3 = self.F[2]
        self.actuation_distance = actuation_distance
        self.delta = delta
        self.lambdas = np.array(lambdas)
        self.Fx = np.array(self.F[:,0])
        self.Fy = np.array(self.F[:,1])
        self.fk()

    def ik(self, alpha=0):
        centroid = [(np.sum(self.Fx)) / 3, (np.sum(self.Fy)) / 3]
        iota = math.acos(((self.e[0] ** 2) - (self.e[1] ** 2) + (self.e[2] ** 2)) / (2 * self.e[0] * self.e[2]))
        A1 = np.array([[1, 1, 1], [-1, 1, 0], [-1, 0, 1]])
        A2 = np.array([[1, 1, 1], [-1, 1, 0], [-1, 0, 1]])
        b1 = np.array([[3 * centroid[0]], [self.e[0] * math.cos(alpha)], [self.e[2] * math.cos(alpha + iota)]])
        b2 = np.array([[3 * centroid[1]], [self.e[0] * math.sin(alpha)], [self.e[2] * math.sin(alpha + iota)]])
        ex = np.linalg.lstsq(A1, b1)[0]
        ey = np.linalg.lstsq(A2, b2)[0]
        self.Ex = np.transpose(ex)
        self.Ey = np.transpose(ey)
        L = np.reshape(self.lambdas, [3, 2])
        C = np.cos(L)
        S = np.sin(L)
        ex = ex[:,0]
        ey = ey[:,0]
        eFx = np.transpose(ex - self.Fx) + C[:, 1] - C[:, 0]
        eFy = np.transpose(ey - self.Fy) + S[:, 1] - S[:, 0]
        A = np.multiply(eFx, eFx) + np.multiply(eFy, eFy)
        T1 = np.array([cm.sqrt(A[0]), -cm.sqrt(A[0])])
        T2 = np.array([cm.sqrt(A[1]), -cm.sqrt(A[1])])
        T3 = np.array([cm.sqrt(A[2]), -cm.sqrt(A[2])])

        zero = np.array([0,0])
        if np.array_equal(T1.imag,zero):
            T1 = T1
        else:
            T1 = np.array([])

        if np.array_equal(T2.imag,zero):
            T2 = T2
        else:
            T2 = np.array([])

        if np.array_equal(T3.imag,zero):
            T3 = T3
        else:
            T3 = np.array([])

        if T1.size == 0 or T2.size == 0 or T3.size == 0:
            self.rho = np.array([])
        else:
            self.rho = np.array([np.transpose(T1), np.transpose(T2), np.transpose(T3)])
            self.rho = np.sort(self.rho, 1)
            unique_list = np.unique(np.array(list(itertools.combinations([1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2], 3))), axis=0)
            self.rho_combi = []
            for a in range(3):
                x = self.rho[a]
                y = unique_list[:, a]
                c = np.transpose([x[i - 1] for i in y])
                self.rho_combi.append(c)
            self.rho_combi = np.array(self.rho_combi)

    def fk(self):
        self.ik()
        self.Ex = np.zeros((3,2))
        self.Ey = np.zeros((3,2))
        self.O = np.zeros((2,2))
        self.rho = np.array(self.actuation_distance)

        zeta = math.pi-math.acos((self.e[0]**2+self.e[1]**2-self.e[2]**2)/(2*self.e[0]*self.e[1]))

        del_C1 = self.delta*(math.cos(self.lambdas[1])+math.cos(self.lambdas[4])-math.cos(self.lambdas[0])-math.cos(self.lambdas[3]))
        del_S1 = self.delta*(math.sin(self.lambdas[1])+math.sin(self.lambdas[4])-math.sin(self.lambdas[0])-math.sin(self.lambdas[3]))
        Xx_1=(self.Fx[1]-self.Fx[0]+del_C1)/self.rho[0]
        Yy_1=(self.Fy[1]-self.Fy[0]+del_S1)/self.rho[0]
        pp_1=self.rho[1]/self.rho[0]
        ep_1=-self.e[0]/self.rho[0]

        del_C3 = self.delta * (
                    math.cos(self.lambdas[1]) + math.cos(self.lambdas[4]) - math.cos(self.lambdas[2]) - math.cos(
                self.lambdas[5]))
        del_S3 = self.delta * (
                    math.sin(self.lambdas[1]) + math.sin(self.lambdas[4]) - math.sin(self.lambdas[2]) - math.sin(
                self.lambdas[5]))
        Xx_3 = (self.Fx[1] - self.Fx[2] + del_C3) / self.rho[2]
        Yy_3 = (self.Fy[1] - self.Fy[2] + del_S3) / self.rho[2]
        pp_3 = self.rho[1] / self.rho[2]
        ep_3 = self.e[1] / self.rho[2]

        a11 = (2 * Xx_1 * pp_1) + (2 * pp_1 * ep_1)
        a12 = 0
        a13 = (2 * Xx_1 * pp_1) - (2 * pp_1 * ep_1)
        b11 = 2 * Yy_1 * pp_1
        b12 = 4 * pp_1 * ep_1
        b13 = 2 * Yy_1 * pp_1
        c11 = (Xx_1**2) + (Yy_1**2) + (pp_1**2) + (ep_1**2) - 1 + (2 * Xx_1 * ep_1)
        c12 = 4 * Yy_1 * ep_1
        c13 = (Xx_1**2) + (Yy_1**2) + (pp_1**2) + (ep_1**2) - 1 - (2 * Xx_1 * ep_1)


        a31 = (2 * Xx_3 * pp_3) + (2 * pp_3 * ep_3 * math.cos(zeta))
        a32 = -4 * pp_3 * ep_3 * math.sin(zeta)
        a33 = (2 * Xx_3 * pp_3) - (2 * pp_3 * ep_3 * math.cos(zeta))
        b31 = (2 * Yy_3 * pp_3) + (2 * pp_3 * ep_3 * math.sin(zeta))
        b32 = 4 * pp_3 * ep_3 * math.cos(zeta)
        b33 = (2 * Yy_3 * pp_3) - (2 * pp_3 * ep_3 * math.sin(zeta))
        c31 = (Xx_3**2) + (Yy_3**2) + (pp_3**2) + (ep_3**2) - 1 + (2 * Xx_3 * ep_3 * math.cos(zeta)) + (2 * Yy_3 * ep_3 * math.sin(zeta))
        c32 = (-4 * Xx_3 * ep_3 * math.sin(zeta)) + (4 * Yy_3 * ep_3 * math.cos(zeta))
        c33 = (Xx_3**2) + (Yy_3**2) + (pp_3**2) + (ep_3**2) - 1 - (2 * Xx_3 * ep_3 * math.cos(zeta)) - (2 * Yy_3 * ep_3 * math.sin(zeta))

        p0 = ((a13 * c33 - a33 * c13)**2 - (a13 * b33 - a33 * b13)**2 + (b13 * c33 - b33 * c13)**2)
        p1 = (2 * (a13 * c33 - a33 * c13) * (a12 * c33 + a13 * c32 - a32 * c13 - a33 * c12) - 2 * (a13 * b33 - a33 * b13) * (a12 * b33 + a13 * b32 - a32 * b13 - a33 * b12)
              + 2 * (b13 * c33 - b33 * c13) * (b12 * c33 + b13 * c32 - b32 * c13 - b33 * c12))
        p2 = (2 * (a13 * c33 - a33 * c13) * (a11 * c33 + a12 * c32 + a13 * c31 - a31 * c13 - a32     * c12 - a33 * c11)
              - 2 * (a13 * b33 - a33 * b13) * (a11 * b33 + a12 * b32 + a13 * b31 - a31 * b13 - a32 * b12 - a33 * b11)
              + 2 * (b13 * c33 - b33 * c13) * (b11 * c33 + b12 * c32 + b13 * c31 - b31 * c13 - b32 
        * c12 - b33 * c11)
              - (a12 * b33 + a13 * b32 - a32 * b13 - a33 * b12) ** 2 + (
                          a12 * c33 + a13 * c32 - a32 * c13 - a33 * c12)**2
              + (b12 * c33 + b13 * c32 - b32 * c13 - b33 * c12) ** 2)
        p3 = (2 * (a12 * c33 + a13 * c32 - a32 * c13 - a33 * c12) * (
                    a11 * c33 + a12 * c32 + a13 * c31 - a31 * c13 - a32 * c12 - a33 * c11)
              - 2 * (a12 * b33 + a13 * b32 - a32 * b13 - a33 * b12) * (
                          a11 * b33 + a12 * b32 + a13 * b31 - a31 * b13 - a32 * b12 - a33 * b11)
              + 2 * (b12 * c33 + b13 * c32 - b32 * c13 - b33 * c12) * (
                          b11 * c33 + b12 * c32 + b13 * c31 - b31 * c13 - b32 * c12 - b33 * c11)
              - 2 * (a13 * b33 - a33 * b13) * (a11 * b32 + a12 * b31 - a31 * b12 - a32 * b11)
              + 2 * (a13 * c33 - a33 * c13) * (a11 * c32 + a12 * c31 - a31 * c12 - a32 * c11)
              + 2 * (b13 * c33 - b33 * c13) * (b11 * c32 + b12 * c31 - b31 * c12 - b32 * c11))
        p4 = (2 * (a11 * c32 + a12 * c31 - a31 * c12 - a32 * c11) * (a12 * c33 + a13 * c32 - a32 * 
        c13 - a33 * c12)
              - 2 * (a11 * b32 + a12 * b31 - a31 * b12 - a32 * b11) * (a12 * b33 + a13 * b32 - a32 
        * b13 - a33 * b12)
              + 2 * (b11 * c32 + b12 * c31 - b31 * c12 - b32 * c11) * (b12 * c33 + b13 * c32 - b32 
        * c13 - b33 * c12)
              - (a11 * b33 + a12 * b32 + a13 * b31 - a31 * b13 - a32 * b12 - a33 * b11) ** 2
              + (a11 * c33 + a12 * c32 + a13 * c31 - a31 * c13 - a32 * c12 - a33 * c11) ** 2
              + (b11 * c33 + b12 * c32 + b13 * c31 - b31 * c13 - b32 * c12 - b33 * c11) ** 2
              - 2 * (a11 * b31 - a31 * b11) * (a13 * b33 - a33 * b13) + 2 * (a11 * c31 - a31 * 
        c11) * (
                          a13 * c33 - a33 * c13)
              + 2 * (b11 * c31 - b31 * c11) * (b13 * c33 - b33 * c13))
        p5 = (2 * (a11 * c32 + a12 * c31 - a31 * c12 - a32 * c11) * (
                    a11 * c33 + a12 * c32 + a13 * c31 - a31 * c13 - a32 * c12 - a33 * c11)
              - 2 * (a11 * b32 + a12 * b31 - a31 * b12 - a32 * b11) * (
                          a11 * b33 + a12 * b32 + a13 * b31 - a31 * b13 - a32 * b12 - a33 * b11)
              + 2 * (b11 * c32 + b12 * c31 - b31 * c12 - b32 * c11) * (
                          b11 * c33 + b12 * c32 + b13 * c31 - b31 * c13 - b32 * c12 - b33 * c11)
              - 2 * (a11 * b31 - a31 * b11) * (a12 * b33 + a13 * b32 - a32 * b13 - a33 * b12)
              + 2 * (a11 * c31 - a31 * c11) * (a12 * c33 + a13 * c32 - a32 * c13 - a33 * c12)
              + 2 * (b11 * c31 - b31 * c11) * (b12 * c33 + b13 * c32 - b32 * c13 - b33 * c12))
        p6 = (2 * (a11 * c31 - a31 * c11) * (a11 * c33 + a12 * c32 + a13 * c31 - a31 * c13 - a32 * 
             c12 - a33 * c11)
              - 2 * (a11 * b31 - a31 * b11) * (a11 * b33 + a12 * b32 + a13 * b31 - a31 * b13 - a32 
        * b12 - a33 * b11)
              + 2 * (b11 * c31 - b31 * c11) * (b11 * c33 + b12 * c32 + b13 * c31 - b31 * c13 - b32 
        * c12 - b33 * c11)
              - (a11 * b32 + a12 * b31 - a31 * b12 - a32 * b11) ** 2 + (
                          a11 * c32 + a12 * c31 - a31 * c12 - a32 * c11) ** 2
              + (b11 * c32 + b12 * c31 - b31 * c12 - b32 * c11) ** 2)
        p7 = (2 * (a11 * c31 - a31 * c11) * (a11 * c32 + a12 * c31 - a31 * c12 - a32 * c11)
              - 2 * (a11 * b31 - a31 * b11) * (a11 * b32 + a12 * b31 - a31 * b12 - a32 * b11)
              + 2 * (b11 * c31 - b31 * c11) * (b11 * c32 + b12 * c31 - b31 * c12 - b32 * c11))
        p8 = (a11 * c31 - a31 * c11) ** 2 - (a11 * b31 - a31 * b11) ** 2 + (b11 * c31 - b31 * c11) 
              ** 2
        T = np.roots(np.array([p0,p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,p6,p7,p8]))
        T = np.round(T,6)

        T1 = T[np.where(T.imag == 0)].real

        self.alpha = 2*np.arctan(T1)
        self.thetas = np.zeros((3,len(self.alpha)))


        A1 = (2 * Xx_1 * pp_1) + (2 * pp_1 * ep_1 * np.cos(self.alpha))
        B1 = (2 * Yy_1 * pp_1) + (2 * pp_1 * ep_1 * np.sin(self.alpha))
        C1 = (Xx_1 ** 2) + (Yy_1 ** 2) + (pp_1 ** 2) + (ep_1 ** 2) + 2 * ep_1 * (Xx_1 * 
        np.cos(self.alpha) + Yy_1 * np.sin(self.alpha)) - 1
        A3 = (2 * Xx_3 * pp_3) + (2 * pp_3 * ep_3 * np.cos(self.alpha + zeta))
        B3 = (2 * Yy_3 * pp_3) + (2 * pp_3 * ep_3 * np.sin(self.alpha + zeta))
        C3 = (Xx_3 ** 2) + (Yy_3 ** 2) + (pp_3 ** 2) + (ep_3 ** 2) + (2 * ep_3 * (
                    Xx_3 * np.cos(self.alpha + zeta) + Yy_3 * np.sin(self.alpha + zeta))) - 1

        CP_2 = np.divide((np.multiply(B3,C1) - np.multiply(B1,C3)),(np.multiply(A3,B1) - 
        np.multiply(A1,B3)))
        Sp_2_num = (np.multiply(A3,C1) - np.multiply(A1,C3))
        SP_2 = np.divide(-Sp_2_num,(np.multiply(A3,B1) - np.multiply(A1,B3)))
        self.thetas[1,:]=np.arctan2(SP_2, CP_2)

        CP_1 = Xx_1 + pp_1 * np.cos(self.thetas[1,:])+ep_1 * np.cos(self.alpha)
        SP_1 = Yy_1 + pp_1 * np.sin(self.thetas[1,:])+ep_1 * np.sin(self.alpha)
        self.thetas[0,:]=np.arctan2(SP_1, CP_1)

        CP_3 = Xx_3 + pp_3 * np.cos(self.thetas[1,:])+ep_3 * np.cos(self.alpha + zeta)
        SP_3 = Yy_3 + pp_3 * np.sin(self.thetas[1,:])+ep_3 * np.sin(self.alpha + zeta)
        self.thetas[2,:]=np.arctan2(SP_3, CP_3)
        
        # solvinf for two different conditions that can arise during running the class through an object apart from the regular outputs
        if self.thetas.shape != (3,2):
            self.thetas = self.thetas[:,:2]

        if self.thetas.shape == (3,0):
            self.thetas = np.resize(self.thetas,(3,2))
            self.thetas = np.zeros((3,2))

        self.Ex[0,:]= np.add(self.Fx[0],self.rho[0] * np.cos(self.thetas[0,:]))
        self.Ex[1,:]= np.add(self.Fx[1],self.rho[1] * np.cos(self.thetas[1,:]))
        self.Ex[2,:]= np.add(self.Fx[2],self.rho[2] * np.cos(self.thetas[2,:]))
        self.Ex = np.transpose(self.Ex)
        max_value = np.max(self.Ex[:,0])
        index = np.where(self.Ex[:,0]==max_value)
        self.Ex = self.Ex[index]
        self.Ey[0,:]=self.Fy[0] + (self.rho[0] * np.sin(self.thetas[0,:]))
        self.Ey[1,:]=self.Fy[1] + (self.rho[1] * np.sin(self.thetas[1,:]))
        self.Ey[2,:]=self.Fy[2] + (self.rho[2] * np.sin(self.thetas[2,:]))
        self.Ey = np.transpose(self.Ey)
        self.Ey = self.Ey[index]
        self.O[:, 0]=np.mean(self.Ex, axis = 1)
        self.O[:, 1]=np.mean(self.Ey, axis = 1)
        self.O = self.O[index]
        self.thetas = np.transpose(self.thetas)
        self.thetas = self.thetas[index]

#getting different combinations of angles that has to be used in the object of the class as lamdas

angles = [[0,1.047,2.0944,3.1415,4.1887,5.23599],[0,1.047,2.0944,3.1415,4.1887,5.23599], 
 [0,1.047,2.0944,3.1415,4.1887,5.23599],[0,1.047,2.0944,3.1415,4.1887,5.23599],[0,1.047,2.0944,3.1415,4.1887,5.23599],[0,1.047,2.0944,3.1415,4.1887,5.23599]]
angle_combos = list(itertools.product(*angles))
# defining values that are going to be constant
e = [100,100,100]
F = [[0,0],[200,0],[100,100*math.sqrt(3)]]
rho = [100,100,100]

Ex_test = np.zeros((343,3))
Ey_test = np.zeros((343,3))
Centroid_test = np.zeros((343,2))
#p_thetas = np.zeros((10,3))

#For ideal Condition to be used for calculating distance later on
id = 0
for i in range(7):
    for j in range(7):
        for k in range(7):
           tester = Three_RPR(e,F,rho)
           Ex_test[id,:] = tester.Ex
           Ey_test[id,:] = tester.Ey
           Centroid_test[id,:] = tester.O
           id += 1
           #p_thetas[id,:] = tester.thetas
           rho[2] = rho[2] + 10
        rho[2] = 100
        rho[1] = rho[1]+10
    rho[1] = 100
    rho[0] = rho[0]+10
rho = [100,100,100]

# initialization for the combinations
Ex_get = np.zeros((len(angle_combos),3))
Ey_get = np.zeros((len(angle_combos),3))
Centroid_get = np.zeros((len(angle_combos),2))
Ex_final_x = np.zeros((343,3))
Ey_final_y = np.zeros((343,3))
O_final = np.zeros((343,2))

id_1 = 0
id_2 = 0
id_3 = 0
```

#to get all the combinations for rho list
for i in range(7):
for j in range(7):
for k in range(7):
dist = []
#for getting all combinations out of the angle_combos list
for l in angle_combos:
get = Three_RPR(e,F,rho,10,list(l))
Ex_get[id_1,:] = np.array([get.Ex[0]])
Ey_get[id_1,:] = np.array([get.Ey[0]])
Centroid_get[id_1,:] = np.array([get.O[0]])
id_1 += 1
dist.append(math.dist(Centroid_test[id_2],get.O[0]))
rho[2] = rho[2] + 10
# to find the index of the maximum distance calculated which helps in extracting Ex and Ey values as well
index = dist.index(max(dist))
id_1 = 0
Ex_final_x[id_3,:] = Ex_get[index,:]
Ey_final_y[id_3,:] = Ey_get[index,:]
O_final[id_3,:] = Centroid_get[index,:]
id_3 += 1
id_2 += 1
rho[2] = 100
rho[1] = rho[1] + 10
rho[1] = 100
rho[0] = rho[0] + 10

Comment: That's a lot of code. Do you expect that anybody reads the full code? What have you tried on your own to improve the performance?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.